# Illustrator - How to clone text fields along anchor points?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm working on a large number of dot-to-dot puzzles and want to speed up the process and make it easier.

Right now I'm trying to find a way to clone one text field along the path so every anchor point of the path will have text field near it.

If you have any information about the way I can do this, please let me know!

Comment: I think you'll need to explain much more. There's no automated method to duplicate a text object where an anchor point exists. Scripting may be your own solution.

Comment: I would group them and just alt-click-and-drag them.

Answer (score 0):

So, here's the answer.

To create dot-to-dot picture you need to trace it with the Pen tool. As the result you should have one not closed path. Copy it to another layer.

**Answer 1.**

> Select the copy of the path and go Select > Object > Direction Handles and press Del. Then go to **Effects > Convert to Shape > Ellipse**. Create an elipse with diameter about 0.01 of any unit. Then set stroke to 1pt. Thats how you recieve the array of dots but ypu still need to label them with numbers.

Copy all of those dots to another level. Then use this script

http://illustrator.hilfdirselbst.ch/dokuwiki/en/skripte/javascript/zamena?redirect=1

to replace the dots with the text label you've created before.

**Answer 2.**

> All you have to do now is to manualy adjust the text objects and fill them with apropriate numbers.

Comment: Like I posted, you didn't explain very well to begin with. Glad you sorted it though.